# Getting the channel name in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to specify the channel my discord bot is posting in using the following code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if message.content.includes("?chan") {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID_HERE')
    console.log(channel)
    channel.send("pong")
  }
})
```

Upon sending the message "?chan", I want the discord bot to print whatever "channel" contains into the console, as well as send the message "pong" to the specified channel. It does neither of these things, and I'm not sure why. Also the rest of the code runs fine, including the parts with code from discord.js.

Comment: I should say, "CHANNEL_ID_HERE" is replaced by the channel ID in my script.

Comment: You need to encase your if statement in `()`

Comment: You may have been confused with Python if statements.

Comment: @Elitezen thanks for your input, but I haven't needed it for any of my other if statements. Either way, I tried that to no avail.

Comment: No, that's the only valid way to write an if-statement in Javascript. View the [Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#syntax). How you are able to compile without any syntax errors is concerning

Comment: Yeah no that's fair, I was using repl.it and i found that it wasn't returning any errors at all... it turns out it doesn't like me having two scripts going to the same bot at the same time. So now I've saved the other script and am only running it off a single one. I decided to take this line out: `const channel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID_HERE')`
and when I do `console.log(channel)` it returns undefined. That seems to be the critical part that isn't working. Thanks for your help so far, any more ideas? I've tried inputting different IDs, to no avail.

Comment: Also you were right, yesterday when I made the post I had 3hrs of sleep and had just gotten off a 7hr train journey.

Comment: Before getting that channel name make sure the channel is cached, If it doesn't then you have to fetch it like `const channel = client.channels.fetch('CHANNEL_ID_HERE')` you will get the channel object if it exists.